# Short circuit parallel to current source explanation

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, current-source

[image]

I was given this circuit in a circuit analysis course and found out using KCL/KVL that all the currents in blue are zero and Ix = -2A. I understand that the current source is connected with both terminals to the same node, so the 2 amperes is coming in and out of the A node.

I know that in a test my professor wants a more elaborated answer, so I though about some different ways of looking at the circuit:

1. The voltage between any given resistor is always zero, because independently of resistor  association, all of the resistors would be connected to the same potential, given a reference, because there can only be one voltage in a node.
2. The node A can be thought of as a resistor with a value of zero, and because no other already existing resistor would be connected in series with all of the 0 ohm resistors, all of the circuit acts like a big current divider, and because I(out) = I(in) * EquivalentResistance/(EquivalenteResistance+0), I(out) = I(in) all of the current would pass through the 0 ohm resistor.

Are these valid ways of looking at the circuit? Is there any other simpler way of looking at it without doing all of the KCL and KVL calculations?

Answer (score 8):

You analysis is correct. The simplest explanation is that:

1. There is a short circuit across the current source
2. The voltage across any short circuit is zero V
3. Therefore, the voltage across the current source is zero V
4. As the only source in the circuit has no voltage, there are no voltages anywhere in the circuit
5. Therefore, the current through any resistor is zero, and the voltage across any resistor is also zero.